# Java program is not runnig in cent os

Tags: mysql, linux, java

I have java program which uses MySQL database

I have generated .class files
using

```
javac -cp mysql.jar IPDOS.java
```

but when I execute the same using

```
java -cp .:mysql.jar IPDOS 1
```

Nothing happens.

Also while compiling it generates following class files.

```
IPDOS.class
IPDOS$1.class
IPDOS$2.class
IPDOS$3.class
```

Comment: class with $ in name is constructor of IPDOS class .

Comment: so how do I execute it?

Comment: @Mr.Noob No it's not. It's an anonymous inner class.

Comment: @Mrx "Nothing happens" can't be right. What do you expect should happen?